# How to upload a data frame to specific folder in SharePoint Using python?

Tags: python, sharepoint, subdirectory

```
buffer = BytesIO()
updated_sheet.to_excel(buffer, index=False)
buffer.seek(0)
file_content = buffer.read()
list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder

I used this code to upload a file in root folder. But I want to upload in respective folder.
```

I tried changing the root folder options but I can't place a file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with specific details, things you have tried so far, and error you are getting.